# SQL loop exiting loop after entering nested loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

The first loop is exited when the second loop is entered for the first time.

```
$score11[]="";
$score22[]="";
$score33[]="";
$scoretotal[]="";
$org[]="";
$p=0;
$sql= "SELECT * from organization WHERE 1"; 
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$organization_id= $row["id"];
$name[$p]=$row["name"];
$org[$p]= $row["id"];



$sql1="SELECT DISTINCT `id_u` from `user_js2` WHERE `organization`='$organization_id'";
$result1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
$id_selfscore=$row1["id_u"];

echo " ". $id_selfscore. "is the id of user";
include('gamescores.php');
echo $score1. $score2. $score3;
$score11[$p]= $score11[$p]+ $score1;
$score22[$p]= $score22[$p]+ $score2;
$score33[$p]= $score33[$p]+ $score3;


}

$scoretotal[$p]= $score11[$p]+$score22[$p]+$score33[$p];
$p=$p+1;



}  
$p_max=$p;
echo $p_max;



array_multisort($scoretotal, SORT_DESC, $org, $score11, $score22, $score33, $name);
```

What is happening: Loop No. 1 (while $row......$p=$p+1) is exited for the first entry into Loop No. 2 (while $row1...... $score3). This means that the line

```
echo " ". $id_selfscore. "is the id of user";
```

is executed only once. 
What should ideally happen: It should take entries for all organization

I tried several things but have not been able to figure out why. Could you help ?

Comment: could it be you somewhere (in the include) overwrite $result?

Comment: If `echo $score1. $score2. $score3;` isn't run then it may be failing in the include, you will need to add this to your question for further help.